# PHP 7.1 usage with Traits in Cake PHP 2 application throws collision errors

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, traits, cakephp-2.x

I'm coding within a Cake PHP 2 application running PHP 7.1, I cannot upgrade the PHP version or Cake version due to business constraints, I'm building out a custom "module" system which has a `Traits` folder using PHP traits, my controller is calling these Traits and each Trait includes other traits as this means I'm easily able to reuse code.

The issue I have is that up until PHP 7.3, PHP throws a fatal error for "collissions with other trait methods", now I don't recall having any duplicate method names in each trait, is there a way I can quietly turn off this specific PHP error or slightly modify my code so that I don't have to rename every single function/method differently in all of the traits that I have?

My dashboard controller is

```php
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'CakeEventManager', 'Event');

// traits
App::uses('Settings', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Presenters', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Statistics', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Jobs', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Dates', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');

class QueueController extends AppController
{
    use Settings, Presenters, Statistics, Jobs, Dates;

    /**
    * View: Queue/dashboard
    */
    public function dashboard()
    {
        // dashboard
    }

}
```

And one, of 7 traits I have called `Jobs`:

```php
<?php

App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');

// Traits
App::uses('Helpers', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Settings', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');

trait Jobs {
    use Helpers, Settings;

    // methods
}
```

Comment: Hello Ryan, have you had any chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't recall having any duplicate method names in each trait

This is not the issue here.
The issue is that you're doing this:

```
trait Jobs {
    use Helpers, Settings;
}
```

and then this:

```
class QueueController extends AppController
{
    use Settings, Presenters, Statistics, Jobs, Dates;
}
```

The fact that the `Jobs` trait uses the `Settings` trait, and the `QueueController` class uses both the `Jobs` and `Settings` traits is creating the issue.

More generally, applying a trait that is already using some other trait, and then including that other trait directly as well causes the issue.

Consider this simpler example:

```
<?php

trait FooTrait {
    function foo()
    {}
}

trait BarTrait {
    function bar()
    {}
}

trait BazTrait {
    use FooTrait, BarTrait;

    function baz()
    {}
}

class Test {
    use FooTrait, BarTrait, BazTrait;

    function doSomething()
    {}
}

$test = new Test;

var_dump(get_class_methods($test));
```

If you execute it, you will see that the same error is thrown:

```
Fatal error: Trait method foo has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on Test in /in/H54W0 on line 20
```

There is no way to "quietly turn off this specific PHP error", this isn't a `warning` or `notice` that you can simply ignore. It's a `fatal error` that will *always* show up, and the only way to solve it is by changing your code so that you don't apply the same trait twice to a class (even *indirectly*, as in your case).

So, four your example, the solution is to remove the `Settings` trait from the `QueueController` class, because it's already included in the `Jobs` trait (and do the same for all the other traits that use traits inside themselves):

```
<?php

App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
App::uses('CakeEvent', 'CakeEventManager', 'Event');

// traits
App::uses('Settings', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Presenters', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Statistics', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Jobs', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Dates', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');

class QueueController extends AppController
{
    use Presenters, Statistics, Jobs, Dates;

    /**
    * View: Queue/dashboard
    */
    public function dashboard()
    {
        // dashboard
    }

}
```

```
<?php

App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');

// Traits
App::uses('Helpers', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');
App::uses('Settings', 'modules/QueueManagerModule/Traits');

trait Jobs {
    use Helpers, Settings;

    // methods
}
```